# How to Generate Separate Word Documents with Unique Filenames from Excel Data using Apache POI and Gradle

Tags: java, excel, gradle, ms-word, apache-poi

I've endlessly been working on a Java application that utilizes Apache POI to perform mail-merge functionality by replacing placeholders in a Microsoft Word template with data from a CSV/Excel file. The codebase is based on the provided GitHub repository (https://github.com/centic9/poi-mail-merge.git).

Currently, the application successfully replaces the markers in the template with data from the CSV/Excel file and stores the results for each line in a single Word document. However, I want to enhance the application to generate a separate Word document for each line in the CSV/Excel file and assign dynamic filenames to each document.

Here's a simplified snippet of the current code in the **`MailMerge`** class from the provided GitHub repository:

```
public class MailMerge {
    public void merge(String templateFile, String csvFile, String outputDir) {
        // Method to perform mail-merge functionality by replacing markers in Word template with CSV data
    }

    private void replaceMarkers(XWPFDocument document, CSVRecord record) {
        // Method to replace markers in the Word document with corresponding data from CSV record
    }
}
```

What changes should I make to the application to create a separate Word document for each line in the CSV/Excel file and traverse the "filename" column(not added yet to Github repository) in the CSV/Excel data and use the diverse filenames in each row to name the corresponding Word document??

As a note, I am using Gradle as the build tool for my project.

Any guidance, code snippets, or suggestions on how to modify the **application** in the provided GitHub repository to achieve this feature would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your expertise!

Comment: Have you looked at [Issue  #27: _Support writing to separate files_](https://github.com/centic9/poi-mail-merge/issues/27)?

Comment: Thanks @trashgod, totally overlooked to Issues :)